# how do I group by in this select statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

```
select '2020-07-02'::date - "duedate"::date as days_passed_since_invoice_was_sent,
       duedate,
       contract_id, 
       paiddate, 
       paymentdueon, 
       component,
       record_valid_from, 
       dueamount, 
       unpaidamount, 
       waivedamount
from dwd_tb_payment_schedule
where record_valid_to = '9999-12-31'
  and unpaidamount > 0
order by duedate asc
```

how do I group by contract_id?
I'm using postgresql 9.6
new edit: So my aim here is to get the total nr of late days a contract_id has.
and then also to show the rest of the information for that specific data point, hence I'm also selecting the rest of the columns in my table. Those columns I don't wish anything to be done with. Just leave them as they are.

Comment: What do you want to do with the columns you do not want to group by? Sum them up? min/max? average? Something else? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per `contract_id` then you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (contract_id) ('2020-07-02'::date - "duedate"::date) as days_passed_since_invoice_was_sent,
       duedate, contract_id,  paiddate, paymentdueon, component,
       record_valid_from, dueamount,  unpaidamount, waivedamount
from dwd_tb_payment_schedule
where record_valid_to = '9999-12-31' and unpaidamount > 0
order by contract_id, duedate asc;
```

This returns the row with the latest `duedate` for each contract (that meets the `where` conditions of course).

Comment: This is perfect Gordon Linof !!! I can't understand how you came to think of it or how I forgot to distinct count them!!! But it deff. did the trick. Let me know if I ever can help you with anything :D CHeers!

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood of your question you want to simply group by one column. I think this can be done in PostgreSQL . For more options you can refer [https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/#:~:text=Introduction%20to%20PostgreSQL%20GROUP%20BY%20clause&text=SELECT%20column_1%2C%20column_2%2C%20aggregate_function(,list%20of%20comma%2Dseparated%20columns.](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/#:%7E:text=Introduction%20to%20PostgreSQL%20GROUP%20BY%20clause&text=SELECT%20column_1%2C%20column_2%2C%20aggregate_function(,list%20of%20comma%2Dseparated%20columns.)

```
select '2020-07-02'::date - "duedate"::date as days_passed_since_invoice_was_sent,
       duedate,
       contract_id, 
       paiddate, 
       paymentdueon, 
       component,
       record_valid_from, 
       dueamount, 
       unpaidamount, 
       waivedamount
from dwd_tb_payment_schedule
where record_valid_to = '9999-12-31'
  and unpaidamount > 0
GROUP BY customer_id
order by duedate asc
```